# Why we cannot declare local const variables in inno-setup [Code]?

Tags: constants, inno-setup, pascal, pascalscript

Do you know why when declaring **local const vars**, the script cannot compile?
Sorry, I know very little pascal and cannot figure out why this is not working!

This example (see ***function CircleArea***) shows that my syntax should be fine.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/pascal/pascal_quick_guide.htm

This is what I am trying to do:

```
//---placed within [Code]
procedure MyLog(const _functionName, _msg: String);
begin
  Log(_functionName + '(): ' + _msg);
end;

function MyExec(const _filename, _params, _dir: String): Boolean;
const // <--- compilation fails in this line!
  MethodName = 'MyExec';
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  MyLog(MethodName, _filename);
  // ... invoke Exec(), etc. ...
end;
//---
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You were trying that right. If Inno Setup were using Pascal it would even work, but since it is based on a custom [`Pascal Script`](http://www.remobjects.com/ps.aspx) language with limitation on declaring local constants, you can't do it that way. You must define your constant globally instead:

```
[Code]
const
  MethodName = 'MyExec';

function MyExec(const _filename, _params, _dir: String): Boolean;
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  MyLog(MethodName, _filename);
  // ... invoke Exec(), etc. ...
end;
```

Comment: I understand. Is there any clever workaround, since global const will not be a solution here! How can I declare a simple variable inside var and initialize it in one step?

Comment: Unfortunately, even this `var X: Integer = 0;` is not allowed. The only way I can think of (considering preprocessor as well) is to declare the variable in the `var` section and initialize its value at the beginning of the function body.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`#define`](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/topic_define.htm) to define "local" constants and then use `ExpandConstant('{#ConstantName}')` whenever you need the value of that constant.

```
function MyExec(const _filename, _params, _dir: String): Boolean;
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  #define MethodName 'MyExec'

  MyLog(ExpandConstant('{#MethodName}'), _filename);
  // ... invoke Exec(), etc. ...
end;
```

Note that the constant isn't actually local, because it is just a **preprocessor definition**. So the functions after `MyExec` could refer to the constant as well, which might be a potential cause of error (but isn't worse than [defining a real global constant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18771231/7571258)). You can **redefine** the same constant in another function or procedure without causing a compile error though.

```
function MyExec(const _filename, _params, _dir: String): Boolean;
begin
  #define MethodName 'MyExec'

  MyLog(ExpandConstant('{#MethodName}'), _filename);
end;

function MyExec2(const _filename, _params, _dir: String): Boolean;
begin
  // if you forget to put the next line, it will log 'MyExec'!!!
  #define MethodName 'MyExec2'

  MyLog(ExpandConstant('{#MethodName}'), _filename);
end;
```

For **added safety**, you might want to `#undef` the "local" constant at the end of the function, in which case InnoSetup would cause a compile error if you'd try to reference it in the next function.

```
function MyExec(const _filename, _params, _dir: String): Boolean;
begin
  #define MethodName 'MyExec'

  MyLog(ExpandConstant('{#MethodName}'), _filename);

  #undef MethodName
end;

function MyExec2(const _filename, _params, _dir: String): Boolean;
begin
  // Forgot to define MethodName, but InnoSetup will cause an error
  // "undeclared identifier: MethodName".
  MyLog(ExpandConstant('{#MethodName}'), _filename);
end;
```

Comment: nice to know this workaround as well...